# SQL Server : concat last column as one field for the same columns

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a table:

Table1

```
fname   lname      job         education
----------------------------------------
john    doe        dentist     harvard
john    doe        dentist     mit
eric    doyle      lawyer      mit
anna    johnson    nurse       yale
```

Trying to select all columns

```
select fname, lname, job, education 
from table1
```

But this returns output like

```
john doe dentist harvard
john doe dentist mit
eric doyle lawer mit
anna johnson nurse yale
```

How can I make it like this:

```
john doe dentist harvard, mit
eric doyle lawer mit
anna johnson nurse yale
```

In other words the same person "john doe", education is concatenated into one column with one row.

Was thinking to write a Python script that:

1. Read column 1,column 2 and other column except the last one, stores the values
2. Check if 2nd row column1 and column2 is different or the same
3. If the same, read column 4 from 1 row and 2 row and concat it into the string
4. Update the 4 column to have concatenated value
5. if different, go further

Need some tips! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1(fname VARCHAR(20), lname VARCHAR(20),job VARCHAR(20),education VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO #Table1

SELECT 'john', 'doe'     ,'dentist', 'harvard' UNION ALL
SELECT 'john', 'doe'     ,'dentist', 'mit'    UNION ALL
SELECT 'eric', 'doyle'   ,'lawer'  , 'mit'    UNION ALL
SELECT 'anna', 'johnson' ,'nurse'  , 'yale'


SELECT T1.fname,T1.lname,T1.job,
STUFF(( SELECT  ', ' + cast(T2.education as varchar(5))
                    FROM    #Table1 T2 
                    WHERE   T1.fname = T2.fname AND T1.lname = T2.lname
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 2, '') as education

FROM #Table1 T1
GROUP BY T1.fname,T1.lname,T1.job
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 1,1 value as education

```
select fname, lname, job, stuff ((
  select ',' + education from #Table1 where fname = t.fname and lname = t.lname and job = t.job 
for xml path('')
),1,1,'') as education
from #Table1 t
group by fname, lname, job
```